# How to prove that infimum and limit inferior commute?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, supremum-and-infimum

How is it possible to prove the following inequality?

### $\inf_{x \in [a,b]} \{\liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)\} \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \{\inf_{x \in [a,b]} f_n(x)\}$

I tried to solve this problem by substituting $"\liminf"$ for $"\sup"$ and $"\inf"$ but I did not be able to solve it.

Comment: Hey Angelo, could you let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: Actually I do not know how it is possible to prove it, for that reason I am asking you. Please help me, thank you so much.

Comment: please give the problem a go, its more important for you to try, than for you to solve it

Comment: I have already tried to solve it but I have not succeed so far, so I need your help.

Comment: The previous comments suggest you to post your thoughts to the problem.  You may click on any one of the related questions with positive scores to see how.

Answer (score 2):

This is false. All we need for a counterexample is a sequence of functions $f_n$ so that for each $x$, the sequence $f_n(x)$ is eventually $1$, but for each $n$, $f_n$ has a zero in the interval $[a, b]$. In this way $\inf_x f_n(x)=0$ and $\liminf_n f_n(x)=1$ and your inequality would imply $1\leq 0$.

We can just take, say, $f_n(x)$ equal to $1$ everywhere, except at $x=a+\frac {b-a}n$ where it's zero.